# E: Cannot create PulseAudio stream: Connection refused

Tags: homebrew, pulseaudio

When I'm running this [package](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/), I'm having this weird issue:

```
E: Cannot create PulseAudio stream: Connection refused
```

When I'm running  pulseaudio --start, I'm having this issue:

```
E: [] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

When I'm running sudo pulseaudio -D, I'm having this:

```
This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
```

When I'm running brew install --without-dbus pulseaudio, nothing changes.

When I'm re-installing (brew reinstall pulseaudio) pulseaudio, nothing changes neither.

I tried what I found on the web but I'm quite lost and not able to figure out what's going on with this package. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. On MacOS High Sierra, you first need to launch `pulseaudio`. Once this is done, you need to launch `minimodem` in a new terminal tab.

Comment: Tried this method on a Raspberry Pi 4, didn`t found it useful!

Comment: No because it's not the same OS